# firebase deploy Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 2

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm starting to learn how to use google cloud function.
I tried the firebase deploy command

`firebase deploy`

but got the following error:

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint

/bin/sh: --: invalid option
Usage:  /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] ...
        /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
GNU long options:
        --debug
        --debugger
        --dump-po-strings
        --dump-strings
        --help
        --init-file
        --login
        --noediting
        --noprofile
        --norc
        --posix
        --protected
        --rcfile
        --restricted
        --verbose
        --version
        --wordexp
Shell options:
        -irsD or -c command or -O shopt_option          (invocation only)
        -abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 2
```

This is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And this is the file my firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've been trying to find a solution.
And the project has been upgraded to Bronze plan.
But couldn't fix it at all. Now I'm really helpless.
Thank you everyone for your help.

I've tried editing various threads. that has already been recommended
But still unable to use firebase deploy command.

Comment: I tried using the firebase deploy command on another macbook with Intel CPU and using the same code was able deploy to cloud functions.

I would like to know why this happened.

Comment: I just encountered the same on an M2 Macbook...

Comment: Have you tried using rosetta as suggested from this [Github link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5403)?

Comment: Was having the same issue on a M1 Macbook Air. Installing Rosetta 2 via `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` did not fix this.

Comment: @Морт did you solved it? We are finding the same issue on an M2...

Comment: I am facing the same problem did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6446#issuecomment-1993579994), this could be caused by using the `curl` installed version of `firebase-cli`.

Uninstalling that:

```bash
curl -sL firebase.tools | uninstall=true bash
```

and re-installing via Homebrew resolved the issue for me

```bash
brew install firebase-cli
```

The solution above also notes that the `npm` installation works:

```bash
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using node 16. It worked just by switching to node v20.